# Drawing using touchesMoved glitching

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-graphics

I am trying to use the touchesBegan, moved, and ended method, although when I use the code attached below, after the finger is released from the screen, when the image is written to the bottom view, it moves the drawing down 70-80px.  I have no idea what could be causing this, as the views are aligned perfectly.

```
 - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    mouseSwiped = NO;
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    lastPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    mouseSwiped = YES;
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
    [self.tempDrawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), brush );
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), red, green, blue, 1.0);
    CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),kCGBlendModeNormal);

    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    self.tempDrawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    [self.tempDrawImage setAlpha:opacity];
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    lastPoint = currentPoint;
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    if(!mouseSwiped) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
        [self.tempDrawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
        CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), brush);
        CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), red, green, blue, opacity);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
        CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
        CGContextFlush(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
        self.tempDrawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.mainImage.frame.size);
    [self.mainImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];
    [self.tempDrawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:opacity];
    self.mainImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    self.tempDrawImage.image = nil;
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}


-(IBAction)paint:(id)sender {

}

-(IBAction)reset:(id)sender {
    self.mainImage.image = nil;
}



- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    red = 0.0/255.0;
    green = 0.0/255.0;
    blue = 0.0/255.0;
    brush = 5.0;
    opacity = 1.0;
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that Imageview & image on that imageview both are of same size.
ie. self.tempDrawImage and self.mainImage frame should be of size